Google Cloud Function slow download speed (Gen 2 Cloud Run)
I have written a gen 2 cloud function with which downloads a large YouTube video at 1080p. Because of this, it downloads the video and audio separately. I have maximized the resources devoted to the function, with 8 CPUs and 32GB storage and 3600s (60 min) timeout. When downloading the video, my cloud function log reports ~500kb/s which is slow, but okay. When downloading the audio however, the download speed drops to ~50kb/s. Does anyone know why this is? Is there somewhere I can change the bandwidth settings? I'm not seeing anything in the documentation.
Here is my function header and the relevant code passage:
@tasks_fn.on_task_dispatched(
        retry_config=RetryConfig(max_attempts=5, min_backoff_seconds=1200),
        rate_limits=RateLimits(max_concurrent_dispatches=10), 
        memory=MemoryOption.GB_32, 
        cpu=8,
        timeout_sec=3600, 
        secrets=["OPENAI_KEY"], )
...

def download_highest_resolution(video_url, output_path):
    logger.info("Downloading")
    
    # Define a dictionary to store information about the downloaded file
    downloaded_file_info = {}
    output_file = f'{output_path}.mp4'

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]',
        'merge_output_format': 'mp4',
        'outtmpl': output_file,  # Specify the output path and template
        'logger': logger,
        'progress_hooks': [lambda d: downloaded_file_info.update(d) if d['status'] == 'finished' else None],
        'concurrent_fragment_downloads': 5,  # Number of fragments to download in parallel
        'n_threads': 5  # Enable multithreading with 5 threads
        }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        try:
            ydl.download([video_url])
            return output_file
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"An error occurred downloading: {e}")
            return None


I tried using pytube and the same issue persists!

You have no control over the max speed of any downloads.  It will always go as fast as it can, considering the quality and speed of the networks between the server instance and the content being downloaded.
